# What syntax does Cognos use?

Tags: sql, cognos

Can we use SQL Server or MySQL syntax in Report Studio?

Comment: Yes. What specific problem are you having? Have you created a data source (in Cognos Connection) and created a Query in Report Studio?

Comment: I am working on an electronic health records and want to extract some info out of it and so need to write queries for that. I was wondering if I need to know cognos sql or I can use MySQL...

Comment: You can write native MySQL queries in report studio. But you lose a lot of benefit of having an enterprise bi tool like Cognos if you're just going to write native queries in Report Studio

Answer (score 2):

There is one MAJOR advantage in relying on built-in SQL generator, instead of using pass-through SQL option available for every query: when your back-end database changes, as along as you did not utilize database-specific features, your report will continue to execute without any changes. So YES, you can provide your own SQL, but there is no reason to.